# How to make maven fail on raw types?

Tags: maven, generics, javac

I want to make maven compile fail if somewhere in the code, raw types (missing generics) are used. I tried the following:

1. The javac does not recognize these errors (the eclipse compiler does); Starting from version 7, the `-Xlint:rawtypes` parameter to `javac` can be used to issue warnings if raw types are used. Unfortunately, I have to use java 6 which does not support this flag.
2. CheckStyle has no rules for such things.
3. PMD also has no abilities to check for raw types.

Are there any other maven-modules or tricks which generate an error if raw types are used?

Comment: There's an undocumented `-Werror` flag for `javac`, that'll fail for all warnings though, not specifically raw types.

Comment: Raw types do not issue a warning on javac in versions before 1.7.

Comment: Could you not use the Java 7 compiler and use the flag, but use target level of 1.6 in the compiler configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would help, but you can use the eclipse compiler in maven

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
         <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```